# Read text file from url android

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am trying to use the textFile approach to notify users of a new update for my application. I do have the app on Playstore and also on google drive. I have succeeded in getting the version code for my app programatically, now the issue is reading the version code in a text file I have hosted on google drive.

I have found the following code but it returns nothing when I use my url from google drive. Am I missing something?

```
private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl)
{
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    // many of these calls can throw exceptions, so i've just
    // wrapped them all in one try/catch statement.
    try
    {
        // create a url object
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);

        // create a urlconnection object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```

Comment: `to use the textFile approach to notify users of a new update`. ??? What would that be? Never heard of.

Comment: Basically you host a text file on a server, containing the version code of your application. When the user launches the application the app checks the version code in the file hosted online and compares it with the current version code of the app which you can get programmatically. If the code versions are not the same then I fire up an alert dialog with an update prompt and if the user clicks 'update' i take them directly to the app hosted on google drive

Comment: `content.append("Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");`. Put that in that catch block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file from url java to android problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100496/read-file-from-url-java-to-android-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution in another post (as suggested in comment):

You've to add:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

to the `onCreate` function.

And this to the manifestFile:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```